# Location of proc filesystem

Tags: proc

Is the proc file system held in memory ( Physical Memory ). Since Kernel constantly updates the proc , I am guessing that the content of the proc have to be in physical memory(RSS) for efficiency. 
Can you any one shed some light on it.

Comment: The Linux /proc File System is a virtual filesystem that exists in RAM (i.e., it is not stored on the hard drive). That means that it exists only when the computer is turned on and running.

Comment: It's not accurate to say that the kernel "updates the proc".  Rather, the proc file system finds the data in the kernel.  For example, if you ```ls /proc/PID/fd```, then procfs will go and read the list of file descriptors for the specified process.

Comment: Thanks @TeeKea ... Can you me the source of this information , I want to read more about it.

Comment: @dave ... " then procfs will go and read the list of file descriptors for the specified process "..in the above line where does procfs go to read the list of fds.

Comment: In the file descriptor table that the process necessarily possesses. Last time I looked, it was held in the task_struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux **/proc** File System is a virtual filesystem that exists in RAM (i.e., it is not stored on the hard drive). That means that it exists only when the computer is turned on and running.

Here are some resources where you can find more details about this:

[The /proc filesystem](http://www.linux-databook.info/?page_id=3771)

[Exploring /proc File System in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/exploring-proc-file-system-in-linux/)

[Discover the possibilities of the /proc directory](https://www.linux.com/news/discover-possibilities-proc-directory)

Hope that helps.